# Display resolution

Tags: display, resolution

I'm a begineer user of a Elementary OS; can anybody help me to indicate how can I have a good resolution of display?  After instalation of Elementary OS is diponible only 4:3. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1 - Open System Settings > Displays and change the resolution manually. If you see a "fake" secondary screen disable it as well.

2 - Open AppCenter and go to the Updates tab. Wait for it to load, and install the  graphics drivers for your system.